# why is my memory game not working? i can't flip the cards or make the game start

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating a memory game for my course and for some reason I can't get the code to work... can someone spot what I have done wrong? I'm still a newbie.

I am trying to flip my cards and play the game however, the game doesn't start which makes me think I have done something wrong at the beginning, any help would be really beneficial! thank you in advance.

I have popped all my code below.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lord of the Rings Memory Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/85df6e4ffa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bilbo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <!--Logo and background-->
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png
        " alt="">
        <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    </section>
    <!---Memory game-->

    <section class="score">
        <ul class="ring-rating">
            <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
            <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
            <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="move-counter">0</span> Moves
        <div class="time-container">
            <span class="timer"><i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i> 00:00 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="reset">
            <button class="btn reset-btn"> Reset <i class="fas fa-redo"></i></button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="modal-win">
        <div class="modal" id="modal-1">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
                <h2>You Did It!!</h2>
                <p>Gollum found his precious! Well Done!</p>
                <img src="images/happy.jpeg" alt="Happy Gollum">
                <button class="btn btn-play-again">Play Again?</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    
        <section class="deck">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/aragorn.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/aragorn.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gandalf.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gandalf.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gollum.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gollum.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/sam.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/sam.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/orc.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/orc.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/sauron.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/sauron.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gimli.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/gimli.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/legolas.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/legolas.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/frodo.jpeg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/frodo.jpeg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/pippin.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <img class="front" src="images/pippin.jpg" alt="">
                <img class="back" src="images/onering.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

        </section>
    
</section>


    <footer>
        <!--Footer-->
    </footer>

    <script rel="stylesheet" src="scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the css

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
    
}

/*----logo----*/

.logo {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
  
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    color: #fbeca3;
    font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;

}

/*-------score tab----*/

.score {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
    padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.ring-rating, li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.move-counter {
    padding: 5px;
    
}

.reset button {
    background: #cf6010;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.time-container {
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 15px;
   color: #fff;
   margin-left: 47%;
   margin-right: 47%;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding: 12px;
}

.time-container span {
    font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.time-container i {
    font-size: 14px;
}

ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}

.card, .btn-reset {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*----modal congrats----*/

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

.modal-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}


/*---Memory Game----*/

.deck {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbeca3);
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    left: 27%;
    width: 640px;
    padding-right: 10px;

}

.card {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: calc(25% - 10px);
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.deck, .card {
    box-shadow: 2px 5px 25px 0 #fbeca3;
    background: #cf6010;
}




.card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
  
}

.card.flip {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}


.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.deck .card.open {
    transform: rotateY(0);
    background: #02b3e4;
    cursor: default;
    animation-name: flipInY;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
    animation-duration: .75s;
}

.deck .card.show {
    font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
    cursor: default;
    
    font-size: 33px;
    animation-name: rubberBand;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
    animation-duration: .75s;
}

.deck .card.unmatched {
    animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
    backface-visibility: visible !important;
    animation-duration: .75s;
    
}

.deck .card.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
/* animations */
@keyframes flipInY {
    from {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    40% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    60% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    80% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: perspective(400px);
    }
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
    from {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }

    30% {
        transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
    }

    40% {
        transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
    }

    50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
    }

    65% {
        transform: scale3d(.95, 1.05, 1);
    }

    75% {
        transform: scale3d(1.05, .95, 1);
    }

    to {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

this is the javascript

```
const deckCards = document.getElementsByClassName(".card");
let cards = [deckCards];

const deck = document.getElementByClassName(".deck");

let opened = [];

let matched = [];

const modal = document.getElementById("modal");

const reset = document.querySelector(".reset-btn");

const playAgain = document.querySelector(".btn-play-again");

const moveCount = document.querySelector(".move-counter");

let moves = 0;

const ring = document.getElementById("ring-rating").querySelectorAll(".ring");

let ringCount = 3;

const timeCount = document.querySelector(".timer");

let time;

let minutes = 0;

let seconds = 0;

let timeStart = false;


function shuffle(cards) {
    var currentIndex = cards.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return cards;
}


window.onload = startGame();

function startGame() {
    opened = [];
   var shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);
         for (var i = 0; i < shuffledCards.length; i++){
        deck.innerHTML = "";
        [].forEach.call(cards, function(item) {
            deck.appendChild(item);
        });
    
    
    }
    cards[i].classList.remove("show", "open", "match", "disabled");
    
}


function removeCard() {
    while(deck.hasChildNodes()) {
        deck.removeChild(deck.FirstChild);
    }
}

function timer() {
    time = setInterval(function() {
        seconds++;
        if(seconds === 60) {
            minutes ++;
            seconds = 0;
        }
        timeCount.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i>' + "Timer" + minutes + "Mins" + seconds + "Secs";
    }, 1000);
}
function stopTime() {
    setInterval(time);
}

function flipCard() {
  cards.classList.toggle('flip');
}
cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));

function resetGame() {
    stopTime();
    timeStart = false;
    seconds = 0;
    minutes = 0;
    timeCount.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i>' + "Timer = 00:00";
    ring[1].firstElementChild.classList.add("fas fa-ring");
    ring[2].firstElementChild.classList.add("fas fa-ring");
    ringCount = 3;
    moves = 0;
    moveCount.innerHTML = 0;
    matched = [];
    opened = [];
    removeCard();
    startGame();
}

function moveCounter() {
    moveCount.innerHTML ++;
    moves ++;
}

function ringCounter() {
    if(moves === 16) {
        ring[2].firstElementChild.classList.remove("fas fa-ring");
        ringCount --;
    }
    if(moves === 22) {
        ring[1].firstElementChild.classList.remove("fas fa-ring");
        ringCount --;
    }
}

function compareTwo(){
    if(opened.length === 2); {
        document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
    }
    if(opened.length === 2 && opened[0].src) {
        match();
    }
    else if(opened.length === 2 && opened[0].src != opened[1].src) {
        noMatch();
    }
}

function match() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        opened[0].parentElement.classList.add("match");
        opened[1].parentElement.classList.add("match");
        matched.push(...opened);
        document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        winGame();
        opened = [];
    }, 600);
    moveCounter();
    ringCounter();
}

function noMatch() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        opened[0].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
        opened[1].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
        document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
        opened = [];
    }, 700);
    moveCounter();
    ringCounter();
}

function addStats() {
    const stats = document.querySelector(".modal-content");
        for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            const statsElement = document.createElement("p");
            statsElement.classList.add("stats");
            stats.appendChild(statsElement);
        }
        let p = stats.querySelectorAll("p.stats");
        p[0].innerHTML = "Time Taken" + minutes + "Minutes" + seconds + "Seconds";
        p[1].innerHTML = "Moves Used" + moves;
        p[2].innerHTML = "Ring Rating" + ringCount + "Out of 3";
}

function displayModal() {
    const modalClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalClose.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";    
    };
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if(this.event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        };
}

function winGame() {
    if(matched.length === 20) {
        stopTime();
        addStats();
        displayModal();
    }
}

deck.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    
        if(timeStart === false) {
        timeStart = true;
        timer();
    }

        flipCard();
    
    function addToOpen() {
        if(opened.length === 0 || opened.length ===1) {
            opened.push(event.target.firstElementChild);
        }
        compareTwo();
    }

});

reset.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
playAgain.addEventListener("click", function(){
    modal.style.display = "none";
    resetGame();
});
```

```js
const deckCards = document.getElementsByClassName(".card");
let cards = [deckCards];

const deck = document.querySelector(".deck");

let opened = [];

let matched = [];

const modal = document.getElementById("modal");

const reset = document.querySelector(".reset-btn");

const playAgain = document.querySelector(".btn-play-again");

const moveCount = document.querySelector(".move-counter");

let moves = 0;

const ring = document.getElementById("ring-rating");

let ringCount = 3;

const timeCount = document.querySelector(".timer");

let time;

let minutes = 0;

let seconds = 0;

let timeStart = false;


function shuffle(cards) {
  var currentIndex = cards.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return cards;
}


window.onload = startGame();

function startGame() {
  opened = [];
  var shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);
  for (var i = 0; i < shuffledCards.length; i++) {
    deck.innerHTML = "";
    [].forEach.call(cards, function(item) {
      deck.appendChild(item);
    });


  }
  cards[i].classList.remove("show", "open", "match", "disabled");

}


function removeCard() {
  while (deck.hasChildNodes()) {
    deck.removeChild(deck.FirstChild);
  }
}

function timer() {
  time = setInterval(function() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds === 60) {
      minutes++;
      seconds = 0;
    }
    timeCount.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i>' + "Timer" + minutes + "Mins" + seconds + "Secs";
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTime() {
  setInterval(time);
}

function flipCard() {
  cards.classList.toggle('flip');
}
cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));

function resetGame() {
  stopTime();
  timeStart = false;
  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  timeCount.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i>' + "Timer = 00:00";
  ring[1].firstElementChild.classList.add("fas fa-ring");
  ring[2].firstElementChild.classList.add("fas fa-ring");
  ringCount = 3;
  moves = 0;
  moveCount.innerHTML = 0;
  matched = [];
  opened = [];
  removeCard();
  startGame();
}

function moveCounter() {
  moveCount.innerHTML++;
  moves++;
}

function ringCounter() {
  if (moves === 16) {
    ring[2].firstElementChild.classList.remove("fas fa-ring");
    ringCount--;
  }
  if (moves === 22) {
    ring[1].firstElementChild.classList.remove("fas fa-ring");
    ringCount--;
  }
}

function compareTwo() {
  if (opened.length === 2); {
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  }
  if (opened.length === 2 && opened[0].src) {
    match();
  } else if (opened.length === 2 && opened[0].src != opened[1].src) {
    noMatch();
  }
}

function match() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    opened[0].parentElement.classList.add("match");
    opened[1].parentElement.classList.add("match");
    matched.push(...opened);
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    winGame();
    opened = [];
  }, 600);
  moveCounter();
  ringCounter();
}

function noMatch() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    opened[0].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
    opened[1].parentElement.classList.remove("flip");
    document.body.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
    opened = [];
  }, 700);
  moveCounter();
  ringCounter();
}

function addStats() {
  const stats = document.querySelector(".modal-content");
  for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    const statsElement = document.createElement("p");
    statsElement.classList.add("stats");
    stats.appendChild(statsElement);
  }
  let p = stats.querySelectorAll("p.stats");
  p[0].innerHTML = "Time Taken" + minutes + "Minutes" + seconds + "Seconds";
  p[1].innerHTML = "Moves Used" + moves;
  p[2].innerHTML = "Ring Rating" + ringCount + "Out of 3";
}

function displayModal() {
  const modalClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalClose.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  };
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (this.event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
}

function winGame() {
  if (matched.length === 20) {
    stopTime();
    addStats();
    displayModal();
  }
}

deck.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  if (timeStart === false) {
    timeStart = true;
    timer();
  }

  flipCard();

  function addToOpen() {
    if (opened.length === 0 || opened.length === 1) {
      opened.push(event.target.firstElementChild);
    }
    compareTwo();
  }

});

reset.addEventListener("click", resetGame);
playAgain.addEventListener("click", function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  resetGame();
});
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(images/background.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*----logo----*/

.logo {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #fbeca3;
  font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
}


/*-------score tab----*/

.score {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
  padding: 10px 0 20px;
}

.ring-rating,
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}

.move-counter {
  padding: 5px;
}

.reset button {
  background: #cf6010;
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.time-container {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 47%;
  margin-right: 47%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.time-container span {
  font-family: 'Bilbo', cursive;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.time-container i {
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.card,
.btn-reset {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*----modal congrats----*/

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*---Memory Game----*/

.deck {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fbeca3);
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  left: 27%;
  width: 640px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  height: calc(25% - 10px);
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.deck,
.card {
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 25px 0 #fbeca3;
  background: #cf6010;
}

.card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.card.flip {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s linear;
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.deck .card.open {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  background: #02b3e4;
  cursor: default;
  animation-name: flipInY;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

.deck .card.show {
  font-size: 33px;
}

.deck .card.match {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 33px;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

.deck .card.unmatched {
  animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  animation-duration: .75s;
}

.deck .card.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* animations */

@keyframes flipInY {
  from {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 90deg);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -20deg);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  60% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -5deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes rubberBand {
  from {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
  }
  65% {
    transform: scale3d(.95, 1.05, 1);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale3d(1.05, .95, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/85df6e4ffa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bilbo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <!--Logo and background-->
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png
        " alt="">
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
  </section>
  <!---Memory game-->

  <section class="score">
    <ul class="ring-rating">
      <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
      <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
      <li class="ring"><i class="fas fa-ring"></i></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="move-counter">0</span> Moves
    <div class="time-container">
      <span class="timer"><i class="fas fa-hourglass"></i> 00:00 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="reset">
      <button class="btn reset-btn"> Reset <i class="fas fa-redo"></i></button>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: please make a snippet of it with the <> button please

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors (F12)?   The snippet that @SébastienGicquel added gives an immediate error `document.querySelectorByClassName is not a function`.  Did you mean `document.querySelector()` (or `document.getElementsByClassName` without the `.` prefix)?

Comment: hey just checked that out, realised i made a mistake with that and also i ahave done that it comes back with an error on line 20 which is.. ```const ring = document.getElementById("ring-rating").querySelectorAll(".ring");```

Comment: I suggest you work through any errors you have, then when you get one that you're stuck on ask a new question on SO.  Note that you'll need to narrow down the issue to the minimal amount of code (see [mcve]).  Also include the error message, not just "an error".